# ng-show is not working in index.html but with other view its works fine in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

what i require is that the hrefs with btns should be shown on the login/signup view and should be hidden on the dashBorad view

index.html

```
<body>
  <div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-bar-block" style="width:20%">
    <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
     <h3 class="w3-bar-item" >Menu</h3>
     <a ng-href="#!/signUp" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" ng-show="btns">SignUp</a>
     <a ng-href="#!/login" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" ng-show="btns">Login</a>
     <a ng-href="#!/addEmployee" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" ng-show="temp">Add Employee</a>
     <a ng-href="#!/userData" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" ng-show="temp">List of Employees</a>
     <a ng-href="#!/logout" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" ng-show="temp" ng-click="func()">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

loginCtrl.js

```
myapp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','myservice','$localStorage','$location',function($scope,myservice,$localStorage,$location) {
   $scope.myobj={};  
   $scope.btns=true;
   $scope.login=()=>{
      myservice.login($scope.myobj).then((response)=>{ //myobj contains email and password
        if(response.responseCode===200){
            alert("Login Successful")
            $scope.btns=false;
            $location.path('/dashBoard');
         }
       },
     (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
    }
```

when i update the value of btns they are still visible on the view. Cannot find what is happening. I have not used parent-child views.

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8UIWTjPWLGze8NvNyqZo)

Comment: what will happen if you by default set `$scope.btns=false;`?

Comment: what will happen if you don't call `$location.path('/dashBoard');`?

Comment: the login and signup hrefs will not be shown if btns is false initially. if dashboard is not called i will be on login view only; just to redirect the user to dashBoard.

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin the result is same as before when stayed on the same view; the hrefs didnt hide.

Comment: Try to reproduce similar behavior in Plunker/Fiddle. I believe te problem exists out of what you posted here

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin: added a plnkr

Comment: @thesoer There is no problem with ng-show. Check with the value of $scope.btns.
I checked your pnkr. I can help you more if you share a login and pswrd as there is no signu page for now, so I can't check your API call

Comment: @Varun Sukheja the signup api is returning correct results. the point is login href should have got hidden

Comment: can you check that $scope.btns is really getting false value  after successful  login?

Comment: @VarunSukheja: the blocked is executed and $scope.btns is set to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Your problem is 2 instances of the same controller. Lets see what we have on start:

```
console.log($scope.$id);  // --> 2
```

However when we click login link, we recreate new `loginCtrl` controller with different id:

```
console.log($scope.$id);  // --> 6
```

So our view is bind to scope with id 2 but we work with id 6

<kbd>[Demo that demonstrates the issue (See console)](https://plnkr.co/edit/OMHS7mKl3QfLr5JvhUNB?p=preview)</kbd>

- 1st instance in  `<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">`
- 2nd instance `$routeProvider.when .... controller:'loginCtrl'`

---

#### Solution:

Since we use `loginCtrl` as root controller
remove `loginCtrl` controller from `$routeProvider`

```
 $routeProvider
  .when('/login',{
    templateUrl:'login.html',
    //controller:'loginCtrl' // we don't need it, it will create new scope
  })
```

<kbd>[Fixed Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0aNEwbzavE1NcVnujScQ?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Comment: if in app.js i don't tell angular which ctrl to use then how does angular gets to know which login() fn to execute when i click submit.

Comment: @theSOer you defined in HTML `<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">` as root wrapper so angular will use `loginCtrl`